# Parsley.js - raising error so that multi-step interface NEXT button identifies that there's error

Tags: parsley.js

I am using parsley.js to control user input validity. If I define the rule via HTML tools such as `required`, `pattern` etc, everything works just fine. That is, if I do something not in line with the rules and press the NEXT button, parsley makes the fields render with red background (as expected).

BUT!

If I define the rule by this code:

```
$('#some_field').on('change', function()
   if (something bad)
   {
       var elem = $('#id_kpp').parsley();
       var error_name = 'multiple_inn_kpp';
       elem.removeError(error_name);
       elem.addError(error_name, {message:'My error message'});
    }
 });
```

rather than HTML tools, I am able to navigate to the next section by pressing the NEXT button as if parsley would not see the invalid input. Though the error raising itself works correctly in that after loosing focus the field renders with red background when loosing focus

Any ideas  what am I doing wrong ?

I hope I put it clear. If something unclear, please ask for additional comments

Answer (score 1):

Just to help you rule out anything simple, have you tried without dropping the braces?

```
if (something bad) {
  var elem = $('#id_kpp').parsley();
  var error_name = 'multiple_inn_kpp';
  elem.removeError(error_name);
  elem.addError(error_name, {message:'Такая пара ИНН/КПП уже существует.'}); 
}
```

Because of the way JavaScript inserts semicolons, it's possible that the if statement is being evaluated (and returning true), but that's the end of the statement. If you don't add a line break after the if statement, you might solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid as much as possible to manually add & remove errors. Instead, use a [custom validator](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#custom).

I would like to get rid of `addError` one day, it's nearly impossible to support it in a consistent way.

Comment: Well, I've taken time to research possible alternatives, but didn't find anything better. What do you mean by custom validators ?

Comment: Did you do a 'find' in the documentation for custom validators? Link added